# javascript click is to be executed first before my anchor tag's knockout click binding function

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, onclick, anchor

I am working on a single page application and there are anchor tags in one of my page. while clicking on any anchor tag, i wrote my logic to execute.It is of the form,

```
$( "a" ).on( "click", function( e ) {

    // My LOGIC CODE  Here to change Window's Location.

  });
```

It is getting executed fine for all my links which are of type (Ex: a href="/page1" )
except for one anchor tag which is using knockout binding.This anchor tag is of form
( a href="/page1" data-bind="click:myFunction"  )

My problem is by clicking that anchor tag MyFunction() is called first and then it is executing the event my event handler and thus is not working properly.

Instead i want to execute my event handler first and then the function(Knockout's Click Binding).

Please provide a solution. THANKS IN ADVANCE .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the source, Luke. ;)

In the function that creates event handlers (like for the `click` binding), [there is this part](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/77de67ea2cfc1ace79b974765d0c7b9400443958/src/binding/defaultBindings/event.js#L34):

```
if (handlerReturnValue !== true) {
    // Normally we want to prevent default action. 
    // Developer can override this be explicitly returning true.
    if (event.preventDefault)
        event.preventDefault();
    else
        event.returnValue = false;
}
```

Just return `true` from your `myFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you may return true on your data-binding like this:

```
<a href="page1" data-bind="click: function () { myFunction(); return true;}">
```